# Sequelize - Updating records through a dynamic form

Tags: sequelize.js

Apologies in advance for the long post ahead.

I have a `Cocktail`, and `Ingredients` models that are associated via `belongsToMany`; and could be updated through a dynamic form. This form allows you to add and delete input fields, and each field represents an `Ingredient`.

[image: Form screenshot]

Before providing my code for updating `Ingredients` , I'd like to preface by saying that my code works... to some degree. I'm interested in writing it more efficiently; while also fixing a bug that occurs randomly.

I'm not sure what triggers the bug; but the bug produces random results. Sometimes everything works fine, where new rows are added, and edited rows are updated normally. But there are times where the new record gets towards the top of the list. For reference, sometimes the New Ingredient in the screenshot, would appear first on top of Gin, rather than at the bottom.

I'd appreciate any input on to fix and improve my attempt.

```
// The object passed when making PUT request:
const { id } = req.params (for current cocktail to update)

ingredients = [ {id:'1', ingredient: 'Gin'}, {id:'2', ingredient: 'Lemon'}, 
{id:'3', ingredient: 'Syrup'}, {ingredient: 'New Ingredient'} ]

// You can see that 'New Ingredient' has no id. When looping through the array, any object 
without an id gets created as a new record.   

const cocktailToUpdate = await Cocktail.findByPk(id, {
  include: [
    {
      model: Ingredient,
      as: 'ingredients',
    },
  ],
});

await ingredients.forEach(async (ingredient) => {

      // if object has no id, then create new ingredient creating the 'New Ingredient'
      if (ingredient.id === undefined) {
        const createdIngredient = await Ingredient.create({
          ingredient: ingredient.ingredient,
        });
        await cocktailToUpdate.addIngredients(createdIngredient);
      }

      // if object has id and ingredient, find and update record
      if (ingredient.id && ingredient.ingredient) { 
        const ingredientToUpdate = await Ingredient.findByPk(ingredient.id);
        await ingredientToUpdate.update({
          ingredient: ingredient.ingredient,
        });
      }
      
      // finally loop through the existing Cocktail we are updating, and compare its ingredients with the ingredients passed into the route at the beginning. Ingredients that do not exist in the passed ingredients object are then deleted from the record.
      const unusedIngredients = await cocktailToUpdate.ingredients.filter(
        (ing) => !ingredients.find((i) => ing.id === i.id)
      );
      await unusedIngredients.forEach(async (ing) => {
        const ingredientToDelete = await Ingredient.findByPk(ing.id);
        await ingredientToDelete.destroy();
      });
    });
```

Edit: Adding my Cocktail and Ingredient models; and relationship definition.

**Cocktail & Ingredient relationship definition**

```
Cocktail.belongsToMany(Ingredient, {
  as: 'ingredients',
  through: Cocktail_Ingredient,
  onDelete: 'cascade',
  hooks: 'true',
});
Ingredient.belongsToMany(Cocktail, {
  as: 'ingredients',
  through: Cocktail_Ingredient,
});
```

**Cocktail Model**

```
const Cocktail = db.define('Cocktail', {
  id: {
    type: UUID,
    defaultValue: UUIDV4,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true,
    },
  },
  description: {
    type: TEXT,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true,
    },
  },
  image: {
    type: STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true,
    },
  },
});
```

**Ingredients Model**

```
const Ingredient = db.define('Ingredient', {
  id: {
    type: UUID,
    defaultValue: UUIDV4,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  ingredient: {
    type: STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true,
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Don’t ever use ```await``` with forEach. Use a for-loop (or any loop without a callback) instead

Comment: thank you, may I ask why await is not recommended for forEach? Also encountering a problem suddenly where a record/ingredient is posting more than once in each call..

Comment: because forEach is not promise-aware. It cannot support async and await. You cannot use await in forEach.

Comment: It's not so much that it doesn't *support* `async/await` as the for loop will block and when you use `await` it will block on each loop until the promise resolves. Only one request at a time and not taking advantage of asynchronous code will make for a slow app.

Comment: `cocktailToUpdate.ingredients.filter()` is not `async` so you shouldn't use `await`

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the `Cocktail.id` and the data for each `Ingredient` ahead of time you can greatly cut down on the I/O to the database by constructing Model instances for each record and then saving/inserting based on the record status.

It's also recommended to use a transaction - if there are an errors you can roll back all of the changes.

```js
// use Sequelize.Op query operators
const { Op } = require('sequelize');

// ... code

let transaction;
try {
  // create a new transaction that we will pass into each query
  transaction = await sequelize.transaction();

  // create an array of IDs that already exist
  const idsToUpdate = ingredients
    // remove any elements that don't have the id set
    .filter(ingredient) => ingredient.id)
    // return the ID for each ingredient
    .map((ingredient) => ingredient.id);

  // delete anything we aren't updating
  await Ingredient.destroy({
    where: {
      id: {
        [Op.notIn]: idsToUpdate,
      },
      cocktail_id: id,
    },
    transaction,
  });

  // this will be an array of promises from calling ingredient.save()
  const promises = ingredients.map(ingredient => 
    // build a new ingredient for all the data passed in
    Ingredient.build(
      // set the parent cocktail_id over the other values
      { ...ingredient, cocktail_id: id },
      // specify if is or isn't a new record based on the ingredient.id
      { isNewRecord: !ingredient.id }
    )
    // calling save will return a promise
    .save({ transaction })
  );

  // this will asynchronously resolve the ingredient.save() from the map
  // and return the model instances
  const instances = await Promise.all(promises);

  // commit the changes
  await transaction.commit();
} catch (err) {
  // rollback the transaction if it is set
  if (transaction) {
    await transaction.rollback();
    delete transaction;
  }
  // throw or handle error
  throw err;
}
```

Comment: hey thank you for this. I'm able to understand the flow, and learned about transactions & build for the first time. However a few questions.. (I really wish we can do line breaks in comments)...

Comment: In the Ingredient.destroy() method, that would essentially delete every ingredient that's not passed wouldn't it? So if I have other cocktails in the record, then ingredients attached to those other cocktails would be deleted. In this case then, would I need to destroy records based on the joint table of `Cocktail_Ingredient`? something like `Cocktail_Ingredient.destroy ({ where: { CocktailId: id, IngredientId: { [Op.notIn]: idsToUpdate }});` But I think this will only delete the joint record, not the Ingredients themselves...

Comment: Lastly, in `Ingredient.build({ ...ingredient, cocktail_id: id })`; what is the second argument for? Because `Ingredient` doesn't have a `cocktail_id` column. `Ingredient` is joint with `Cocktail`, so in the joint table there are `CocktailId` and `IngredientId`. I looked into the documentation, and the examples do not show a second argument for `.build`

Comment: I'm so sorry, for the multiple comments. But another idea I have is to just delete all ingredients associated with the cocktail. Then make new ones. Every ingredient record is unique to each cocktail, and aren't shared with other cocktails. I feel deleting them and making new entries on each PUT request saves headache (maybe)?

Comment: You're correct about `Ingredient.destroy()`, I forgot to include `CocktailId: id` in the where criteria to only delete the ones related to the cocktail you are working with. I didn't know what format you were using for the tables/models so I used example IDs, I will update the answer.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying there is a relational table? Did you specify the relationship with the `through` property? That's probably a better design but not specified in your question, can you include the `sequelize.define()` for the models?

Comment: I've added the models for both, and `Cocktail` and `Ingredients`, and their relationship definition. I think in a way, what I'm trying to accomplish when updating the ingredients for a cocktail; is to `cocktail.setIngredients(updatedIngredients)`, then delete the ingredients that were previously assigned to the cocktail. I think also it's helpful to visualize the scenarios possible when updating.... to be continued

Comment: If you look at the screenshot; there are 3 possible scenarios with ingredients. 1. You can edit an ingredient (change Gin to Lemon for instance) which would update the record. 2. Delete an ingredient, which should delete the ingredient from record. 3. Add an ingredient, creating a new record... Would it be inefficient to just delete all records of ingredients assigned to a recipe, and (re)create them in the PUT request? So if I change Gin to Lemon in the screenshot, and add a 5th ingredient; then delete all 4 existing ingredients for the cocktail, then create 5 ingredients for the cocktail.

Comment: @giantqtipz you could technically do that but yes, it would be less efficient, and also it would lead to database fragmentation.